# how to see the content of a particular file in .tar.gz archive without unzipping the contents?

Tags: python, bash

for ex abc.tar.gz has

abc/file1.txt
abc/file2.txt
abc/abc1/file3.txt
abc/abc2/file4.txt

i need to read/display the contents of file3.txt without extracting the file.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: And I thought that was about the same thing... Do you mean that you don't want to extract it to a file on disk?

Comment: no the compressed file is a big file with too many folders and files inside and i dont have enough space/use for the whole uncompressed one, also i dont need the entire contents of the particular file in the tar.gz. i found ans though tar -xzf file.tar.gz -O file/particularfile.txt and pipe to csplit for pattern. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

```
import tarfile
spam = tarfile.open( "abc.tar.gz" )
if "abc/abc1/file3.txt" in spam.getnames():
    with spam.extractfile( "abc/abc1/file3.txt" ) as ham:
        print ham.read()
```

See [tarfile](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open).

Comment: thanks for ans, but my vote goes to bash since its easy for me to pipe to look for patterns on the particular file.

Comment: Fair enough -- though you could do the same thing in python; `getnames` returns an array of files in the archive that you could search/analyse. Is there any particular reason the question is tagged `python`, btw? =p

Answer (score 5):

```
tar -xzf mytar.tar.gz --to-command=cat filename.in.archive
```

Comment: your ans helped. i was looking for some pattern in the particular file. pipe to csplit helped me  
tar -xzf file.tar.gz -O file/file.txt |csplit -s  - "/regex /" {no_of_times} > /dev/null  
thanks