# How to check if it is a file or folder for an archive in python?

Tags: python, zip, archive

I have an archive which I do not want to extract but check for each of its contents whether it is a file or a directory.

os.path.isdir and os.path.isfile do not work because I am working on archive. The archive can be anyone of tar,bz2,zip or tar.gz(so I cannot use their specific libraries). Plus, the code should work on any platform like linux or windows. Can anybody help me how to do it?

Comment: no, because the archive can be of any type (there are so many types of archives)

Comment: This should be possible in theory by parsing the file... but  why can't you extract them?

Comment: I have to upload the archive and extract it then but before uploading, I have to implement a few checks.

Comment: Maybe one of these get your started:

Comment: [click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018512/reading-tar-file-contents-without-untarring-it-in-python-script) or [click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33592099/how-do-i-list-contents-of-a-gz-file-without-extracting-it-in-python) or [click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369732/how-to-see-the-content-of-a-particular-file-in-tar-gz-archive-without-unzipping)

Comment: Also of course you could check the filetype and then use the respective library.

Comment: there are so many types of archives that it is just not possible to write separate code for each of them. Currently, I try to use archive.getall_members() and try to iterate over it to check that whether its contents are a file or a folder but I do not know how?

Comment: there are so many types of archives that it is just not possible to write separate code for each of them <- try to apply the strategy pattern. Most of the could would be shared for the archive types, with minimal changes for the different library calls.

Comment: I did not get what you are trying to say.. can you please elaborate it?

Comment: just a typo, I meant "code", not "could". Too late to edit.

Answer (score 17):

You've stated that you need to support "tar, bz2, zip or tar.gz".  Python's `tarfile` module will automatically handle gz and bz2 compressed tar files, so there is really only 2 types of archive that you need to support: tar and zip. (bz2 by itself is not an archive format, it's just compression).

You can determine whether a given file is a tar file with `tarfile.is_tarfile()`. This will also work on tar files compressed with gzip or bzip2 compression. Within a tar file you can determine whether a file is a directory using `TarInfo.isdir()` or a file with `TarInfo.isfile()`.

Similarly you can determine whether a file is a zip file using `zipfile.is_zipfile()`. With `zipfile` there is no method to distinguish directories from normal file, but files that end with `/` are directories.

So, given a file name, you can do this:

```
import zipfile
import tarfile

filename = 'test.tgz'

if tarfile.is_tarfile(filename):
    f = tarfile.open(filename)
    for info in f:
        if info.isdir():
            file_type = 'directory'
        elif info.isfile():
            file_type = 'file'
        else:
            file_type = 'unknown'
        print('{} is a {}'.format(info.name, file_type))

elif zipfile.is_zipfile(filename):
    f = zipfile.ZipFile(filename)
    for name in f.namelist():
         print('{} is a {}'.format(name, 'directory' if name.endswith('/') else 'file'))

else:
    print('{} is not an accepted archive file'.format(filename))
```

When run on a tar file with this structure:

```
(py2)[mhawke@localhost tmp]$ tar tvfz /tmp/test.tgz
drwxrwxr-x mhawke/mhawke     0 2016-02-29 12:38 x/
lrwxrwxrwx mhawke/mhawke     0 2016-02-29 12:38 x/4 -> 3
drwxrwxr-x mhawke/mhawke     0 2016-02-28 21:14 x/3/
drwxrwxr-x mhawke/mhawke     0 2016-02-28 21:14 x/3/4/
-rw-rw-r-- mhawke/mhawke     0 2016-02-28 21:14 x/3/4/zzz
drwxrwxr-x mhawke/mhawke     0 2016-02-28 21:13 x/2/
-rw-rw-r-- mhawke/mhawke     0 2016-02-28 21:13 x/2/aa
drwxrwxr-x mhawke/mhawke     0 2016-02-28 21:13 x/1/
-rw-rw-r-- mhawke/mhawke     0 2016-02-28 21:13 x/1/abc
-rw-rw-r-- mhawke/mhawke     0 2016-02-28 21:13 x/1/ab
-rw-rw-r-- mhawke/mhawke     0 2016-02-28 21:13 x/1/a
```

The output is:

```
x is a directory
x/4 is a unknown
x/3 is a directory
x/3/4 is a directory
x/3/4/zzz is a file
x/2 is a directory
x/2/aa is a file
x/1 is a directory
x/1/abc is a file
x/1/ab is a file
x/1/a is a file
```

Notice that `x/4` is "unknown" because it is a symbolic link.

There is no easy way, with `zipfile`, to distinguish a symlink (or other file types) from a directory or normal file. The information is there in the `ZipInfo.external_attr` attribute, but it's messy to get it back out:

```
import stat

linked_file = f.filelist[1]
is_symlink = stat.S_ISLNK(linked_file.external_attr >> 16L)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `string.endswith(string)` method to check whether it has the proper file-name extension:

```
filenames = ['code.tar.gz', 'code2.bz2', 'code3.zip']
fileexts = ['.tar.gz', '.bz2', '.zip']

def check_extension():
    for name in filenames:
        for ext in fileexts:
            if name.endswith(ext):
                print ('The file: ', name, ' has the extension: ', ext)


check_extension()
```

which outputs:

```
The file:  code.tar.gz  has the extension:  .tar.gz
The file:  code2.bz2  has the extension:  .bz2
The file:  code3.zip  has the extension:  .zip
```

You would have to create a list of the file extensions for each and every archive file-type you'd want to check against, and would need to load in the file-name into a list where you can easily execute the check, but I think this would be a fairly effective way to solve your issue.

Comment: I am checking the file type of the contents of the archive and not that of the archive itself. Please read my solution. It works.

Comment: Apologies for my mistake, my interpretation of your question was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. It is that we can use two commands: archive.getall_members() and archive.getfile_members().

We iterate over each of them and store the file/folder names in two arrays a1(contains file/folder names) and a2(contains file names only). If both the arrays contain that element, then it is a file otherwise it is a folder.

Comment: What is `archive.getall_members()`. What package is this?

Comment: It is utils.archives

Comment: And what is the `utils` package? From what? Django?

Comment: yeah it is from django.

Comment: I can't find either of those functions in any version of Django. Which version are you using? You should also be aware that those functions, as others from `django.utils` could disappear in a future release of Django.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python-magic module and parse it's output.

```
[root@jasonralph ~]# yum install python-pip

[root@jasonralph ~]# pip install python-magic

[root@jasonralph ~]# cat py_file_check.py
#!/usr/bin/python

import magic
print magic.from_file('jason_ralph_org_20160215.tar.gz')

[root@jasonralph ~]# file jason_ralph_org_20160215.tar.gz
jason_ralph_org_20160215.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last   modified: Mon Feb 29 01:33:25 2016
```

> ```
> > [root@jasonralph ~]# python py_file_check.py
> >         gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Mon Feb 29 01:33:25 2016
> ```

Comment: I am checking the file type of the contents of the archive and not that of the archive itself. Please read my solution. It works