# Traverse tar file recursively and extract all files with specified extension

Tags: python, directory, compression, tar

I have a tar.gz file which contains a hierarchy of files, folders and other tar.gz files within them.

I have no idea of the depth of the directory structure, it will vary according to the file

I would like to know a way to write a Python script which will traverse through all the compressed files and extract files with specified file extensions

Comment: Try the examples from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#examples). And also try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35690896/4502878) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`tarfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) module top open tar.gz files, then call `getmembers()` to get tar file members. Open the ones you want.

Those that are `.tar.gz` members should be processed recursively (pretty much like you did the top file). The only difference is you'll probably need to pass a file-like-object to `TarFile.open` instead of a filename.

Comment: Its not that I just have tar files within tar, it could be any compression. I have tried recursive traversal, but my Python script fails at some point

Comment: You need to handle all kinds of compression you want to support. As for recursion failing - you probably have a bug.